# How to store the pandas groupby() objects in the same variable with different indexes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Suppose I have a data frame `df` with three columns

```
df=
id  date       value
A  02-04-2000  3
A  03-04-2000  8
B  04-04-2000  12
B  02-04-2000  7
C  03-04-2000  5
C  04-04-2000  2
```

I am interested in grouping the data based on `df['id']` column and store the values in a variables  `new`. The `new` should store the values in such a way that when I call `new[1]` it should return elements corresponding to `id = A` leaving the `id` column and new[2] should return the elements corresponding to `id = B` and so on.

example output:

```
new[1]=
date       value
02-04-2000  3
03-04-2000  8

new[2]=
date        value
04-04-2000  12
02-04-2000  7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all solutions is used [`DataFrame.groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with remove `id` column by [`DataFrame.drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html).

If possible indexing by `0, 1,...` and output is list of `DataFrame`s:

```
new = [g.drop('id', axis=1) for _, g in df.groupby('id')]
print (new[0])
         date  value
0  02-04-2000      3
1  03-04-2000      8
```

If output is dictionary of `DataFrame`s, here are create consecutive groups:

```
new = {k: g.drop('id', axis=1) 
                       for k, g in  df.groupby(df['id'].ne(df['id'].shift()).cumsum())}
print (new[1])
         date  value
0  02-04-2000      3
1  03-04-2000      8
```

Similar solution (without consecutive groups):

```
new1 = {k: g.drop('id', axis=1) for k, g in  df.groupby('id')}
print (new1['A'])
         date  value
0  02-04-2000      3
1  03-04-2000      8
```

---

Grouping by cosecutive group I try explain in another data:

```
 print (df)

  id        date  value
0  A  02-04-2000      3
1  A  03-04-2000      8
2  B  04-04-2000     12
3  A  02-04-2000      7
4  A  03-04-2000      5
5  C  04-04-2000      2
    
new = {k: g.drop('id', axis=1) 
                       for k, g in  df.groupby(pd.factorize(df['id'])[0]+1)}


#all A rows is first group
print (new[1])
         date  value
0  02-04-2000      3
1  03-04-2000      8
3  02-04-2000      7
4  03-04-2000      5


#all C rows is third group   
print (new[3])
         date  value
5  04-04-2000      2
```

Grouping by consecutive groups:

```
print (df)

  id        date  value
0  A  02-04-2000      3 <- 1group
1  A  03-04-2000      8 <- 1group
2  B  04-04-2000     12 <- 2group
3  A  02-04-2000      7 <- 3group
4  A  03-04-2000      5 <- 3group
5  C  04-04-2000      2 <- 4group
    

new = {k: g.drop('id', axis=1) 
                       for k, g in  df.groupby(df['id'].ne(df['id'].shift()).cumsum())}

#first group   
print (new[1])
         date  value
0  02-04-2000      3
1  03-04-2000      8

#fourth group
print (new[3])
         date  value
3  02-04-2000      7
4  03-04-2000      5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# generate new dict
new = {}
# get unique id values
unique_ids = df['id'].unique()

for index, value in zip(range(len(unique_ids)), unique_ids):
    new[index] = df[df['id'] == value].copy()
```